# What does NOTIFY=&SYSUID mean?

Tags: jcl

What does `NOTIFY=&SYSUID` mean on the first line of a JCL?  For example in the below declaration:

```
//DEV1000D JOB (0998,DEV,000,US),'TEST',        
//         CLASS=D,MSGCLASS=V,NOTIFY=&SYSUID
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NOTIFY=&SYSUID` indicates that the user who submitted the job should be notified when it completes.

From the MVS JCL manual:
**NOTIFY:**

> In a non-APPC scheduling environment, requests that the system send a message to a
> userid when this background job completes.

**&SYSUID**

> The system replaces &SYSUID with the user ID under whose authority the job will run, which is normally one of the following:
>
> - The USER parameter from the JOB statement, if specified, or
> - The user ID from which the job was submitted.

Comment: Another thing about &SYSUID you can only use it in the jobcard. You can use it as say part of a dataset name in the JCL below the jobcard.

Comment: @Deuian The second can should be can't?

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain what is **NOTIFY**

NOTIFY statement is to direct the system ,where it has to send the success failure message after completing the job.

`syntax :NOTIFY=userid/&SYSUID`

Simply it says to which user the notification has to be send &SYSID is the userid from which the jcl is submitted

eg: NOTIFY=TRC033 will send success/failure message to trc033

NOTIFY=&SYSUID will send send/failure message to user submitting the job